# Java OkhttpClient sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target

Tags: java, ssl, postman, okhttp, client-certificates

Postman request with certificate, key is working, But relevant code for Java - Okhttp client is failing

Adding crt, key in the postman is working
[image]

Relevant code for Java

```
import okhttp3.OkHttpClient;
import okhttp3.Request;
import okhttp3.Response;
import javax.net.ssl.SSLContext;
import javax.net.ssl.TrustManagerFactory;
import javax.net.ssl.X509TrustManager;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.security.*;
import java.security.cert.*;
import java.security.spec.PKCS8EncodedKeySpec;
import java.util.Base64;

public class Main {

  private static X509Certificate loadCertificateFromFile(File file)
      throws CertificateException, IOException {
    FileInputStream inputStream = new FileInputStream(file);
    CertificateFactory certificateFactory = CertificateFactory.getInstance("X.509");
    X509Certificate certificate =
        (X509Certificate) certificateFactory.generateCertificate(inputStream);
    inputStream.close();
    return certificate;
  }

  private static PrivateKey loadPrivateKeyFromFile(File file)
      throws GeneralSecurityException, IOException {
    FileInputStream inputStream = new FileInputStream(file);
    byte[] keyBytes = new byte[inputStream.available()];
    inputStream.read(keyBytes);
    inputStream.close();
    String keyBytesStr =
        new String(keyBytes)
            .replace("-----BEGIN PRIVATE KEY-----", "")
            .replace("-----END PRIVATE KEY-----", "")
            .replaceAll("\\s", "");

    // Assuming the private key is in PKCS#8 format
    PKCS8EncodedKeySpec keySpec = new PKCS8EncodedKeySpec(Base64.getDecoder().decode(keyBytesStr));
    KeyFactory keyFactory = KeyFactory.getInstance("RSA");
    return keyFactory.generatePrivate(keySpec);
  }

  public static void main(String[] args) throws GeneralSecurityException, IOException {

    File crtFile = new File("/oath/chain.crt");
    File keyFile = new File("/path/private.key");
    File serverFile = new File("/path/abc.com.pem");
    X509Certificate certificate = loadCertificateFromFile(crtFile);
    X509Certificate serverCertificate = loadCertificateFromFile(serverFile);
    // Load the private key from KEY file
    PrivateKey privateKey = loadPrivateKeyFromFile(keyFile);

    // Load the certificate and private key into KeyStore
    KeyStore keyStore = KeyStore.getInstance("PKCS12");
    keyStore.load(null, null);
    keyStore.setKeyEntry("alias", privateKey, null, new X509Certificate[] {certificate});
    keyStore.setCertificateEntry("server", serverCertificate);

    TrustManagerFactory trustManagerFactory =
        TrustManagerFactory.getInstance(TrustManagerFactory.getDefaultAlgorithm());
    trustManagerFactory.init(keyStore);

    // Create SSLContext and configure it with KeyManager and TrustManager
    SSLContext sslContext = SSLContext.getInstance("TLS");
    sslContext.init(null, trustManagerFactory.getTrustManagers(), null);

    // Create OkHttpClient with the configured SSLContext
    OkHttpClient client =
        new OkHttpClient.Builder()
            .sslSocketFactory(
                sslContext.getSocketFactory(),
                (X509TrustManager) trustManagerFactory.getTrustManagers()[0])
            .build();

    // Make a request using the OkHttpClient
    Request request = new Request.Builder().url("<URL>").build();

    try (Response response = client.newCall(request).execute()) {
      // Process the response
      System.out.println(response.code());
      System.out.println(response.body().string());
    }
  }
}
```

Error

> Caused by: sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target

Comment: Most likely the server is misconfigured and does not send the complete certificate chain (which is supposed to do except for the root CA cert). If the server is public you can test it using https://www.ssllabs.com/ssltest/ for certificate chain and other problems.

Comment: @Robert But it was successful in postman

Comment: @Robert and also there are no problems in ssltest

Comment: **client != server:** The **cert&key configured in postman** authenticate the _client_ (aka mutual auth), which **corresponds to KeyManager in JSSE**; this client cert CANNOT be used to validate the server, which corresponds to TrustManager in JSSE or okhttp3, and if ssllabs approves of the server cert it's using a 'normal' CA so **you need not and should not customize your TrustManager**.